# Can I add a variable in a format string?

Tags: c#

I'm new to this and just did my first Hello World program yesterday.

I'm wondering if i can change the f5 to a varible.

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:f5}", theAnswer);
```

The 5 would change depending on the user input.

This didn't work, but is it possible to use something like it,

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:f + myVarible}", theAnswer);
```

If not, any suggestions on what route I should take would be helpful.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do. Can you give an example of what output you would expect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try with:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", theAnswer.ToString("f" + myVariable));
```

Or, if you only have the `{0}` in:

```
Console.WriteLine(theAnswer.ToString("f" + myVariable));
```

Comment: Thank you! I will have a go at this and see where it takes me :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try solve this by changing your code:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:f + myVarible}", theAnswer);
```

to this

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", usersAnswer.ToString("f" + myVariable));
```

Comment: @Jon if this solved your issue please accept answer and vote up :) Thanks